# How to use image manipulation library Glide with plain PHP

Tags: php, image-manipulation, php-glide

I'm trying to use PHP Glide image manipulation library for one of my projects. I've followed their docs given at here - http://glide.thephpleague.com/1.0/simple-example/ .

I've created a "routes.php". Here is my code.

```
<?php
require 'vendor/autoload.php';

// Setup Glide server
$server = League\Glide\ServerFactory::create([
    'source' => 'img/users/source',
    'cache' => 'img/users/cache',
]);

// echo '<pre>';
// print_r($server);
// echo '</pre>';

// You could manually pass in the image path and manipulations options
//$server->outputImage('users/1.jpg', ['w' => 300, 'h' => 400]);
$server->outputImage('img/users/source/1.jpg', ['w' => 300, 'h' => 400]);
```

My images are in folder called 'img' & folder structure is like this -

[image]

So, according to the doc & my understanding when I execute "routes.php" file through the browser it should return me an image URL which I've hardcoded in the code. But, I'm getting an exception instead.

Exception -

PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'League\Glide\Filesystem\FileNotFoundException' with message 'Could not find the image `img/users/source/1.jpg`.' in /var/www/testing/glide/vendor/league/glide/src/Server.php:465\nStack trace:\n#0 /var/www/testing/glide/vendor/league/glide/src/Server.php(433): League\Glide\Server->makeImage('img/users/sourc...', Array)\n#1 /var/www/testing/glide/routes.php(16): League\Glide\Server->outputImage('img/users/sourc...', Array)\n#2 {main}\n  thrown in /var/www/testing/glide/vendor/league/glide/src/Server.php on line 465

Need some to understand how to work with this glide.

Comment: I have same code structure and it is displayed nothing.please help !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this next to the require:

```
use League\Flysystem\Adapter\Local;
use League\Flysystem\Filesystem;
use League\Glide\ServerFactory;
```

Like this:

```
<?

require '../vendor/autoload.php';

use League\Flysystem\Adapter\Local;
use League\Flysystem\Filesystem;
use League\Glide\ServerFactory;

// Setup Glide server
$server = League\Glide\ServerFactory::create([
    'source' => '../assets/img/source',
    'cache' => '../assets/img/cache',
]);

// You could manually pass in the image path and manipulations options
$server->outputImage('01.jpg', ['w' => 300, 'h' => 400]);
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the reply. I tried this but still not working. I'm getting the same error again. Can you give some sample code which is working on your side?

Comment: Hey, edited the answer, the above example works for me.
ps. i have changed the folder, so i need '../', in your case, you don´t

Comment: Can you tell me about your file & folder structure? Everything looks similar to mine. I've updated my post with an image of the folder structure.

Comment: I have the images in "assets/img/source" and "assets/img/cache", and a folder where I have a script that " serves" the image, as I´m not using a framework.

Comment: I got it. In the last line rather than this ```$server->outputImage('img/users/source/1.jpg', ['w' => 300, 'h' => 400]);``` it should be ```$server->outputImage('1.jpg', ['w' => 300, 'h' => 400]);``` It's now fixed. Thanks a lot. I really appreciate help.

Comment: I have same code structure and it is displayed nothing.please help !

Comment: i got error Class 'League\Glide\ServerFactory' not found. Do you know how to fix it?