# image manipulation with Glide is not working

Tags: php, image-manipulation, php-glide

I am using Glide image library without framework.I follow the tutorial
http://glide.thephpleague.com/1.0/installation/

My question is most likely [How to use image manipulation library Glide with plain PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36527666/how-to-use-image-manipulation-library-glide-with-plain-php) but it is not my question and that solution not work for me.

when I point url localhost/myproject/routes.php nothing displayed.
when I print the $server variable it is printed.

```
<?php
require 'vendor/autoload.php';
use League\Flysystem\Adapter\Local;
use League\Flysystem\Filesystem;
use League\Glide\ServerFactory;


// Setup Glide server
$server = League\Glide\ServerFactory::create([
    'source' => 'img/users/source',
    'cache' => 'img/users/cache',
]);

echo '<pre>';
print_r($server);
echo '</pre>';



echo $server->outputImage('users/1.jpg', ['w' => 300, 'h' => 400]);
```